# I want to show the modal when visit the page by using vue-js-modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I don't need a button to click but I want to show modal immediately when I visit the page. I tried to add **@before-open** but it's not happen, why? It's doesn't show anything on log. I'm a beginner, please help me.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <modal name="hello-world" @before-open="beforeOpen">hello, world!</modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      localTime: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    beforeOpen(event) {
       console.log(event);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: What library are you using for the modal?

Comment: @Spiderman it's vue-js-modal. this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal

Comment: IF used import modal from './components/modal.vue';

Then you can use 
data () {
      return {
        isModalVisible: false
      };
    },